# Multi-leveled XML file reading in C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I want to read a multi-leveled xml file and store it in an object list. The XML file holds gender which in turn holds 0 to n attributemodifier and 0-n skill modifier. One can assume the attributemodifiers resp. skillmodifiers tag will always exist. It fails at loading the child nodes "attributemodifiers" and "skillmodifiers", my quesiton is why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<genders>
    <gender>
        <name>Female</name>
        <attributemodifiers>
            <attributemodifier>
                <attribute>Agility</attribute>
                <value>1</value>
            </attributemodifier>
        </attributemodifiers>       
        <skillmodifiers>
            <skillmodifier>
                <attribute>Charm</attribute>
                <value>1</value>
            </skillmodifier>
        </skillmodifiers>
    </gender>
    <gender>
        <name>Male</name>
        <attributemodifiers>
            <attributemodifier>
                <attribute>Strength</attribute>
                <value>1</value>
            </attributemodifier>
            <attributemodifier>
                <attribute>Focus</attribute>
                <value>-1</value>
            </attributemodifier>
        </attributemodifiers>       
        <skillmodifiers>
            <skillmodifier>
                <attribute>Intimidation</attribute>
                <value>1</value>
                <attribute>Coercion</attribute>
                <value>1</value>
            </skillmodifier>
        </skillmodifiers>
    </gender>
</genders>
```

The current code I have:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
doc.Load (@"genders.xml");

XmlNodeList gs = doc.SelectNodes ("genders/gender");

foreach (XmlNode g in gs) {

    Gender tg = new Gender ();
    tg.Name = g.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
    tg.Desc = g.SelectSingleNode("desc").InnerText;

    XmlNodeList ams = doc.ChildNodes;

    foreach (XmlNode am in ams) {
        int ta = (int)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(AttributeName), am.SelectSingleNode ("attribute").InnerText);
        int tv = System.Convert.ToInt32(am.SelectSingleNode ("value").InnerText);
        tg.AddAttributeModifier (ta, tv);
    }

    XmlNodeList sms = doc.ChildNodes;

    foreach (XmlNode sm in sms) {
        int ts = (int)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(SkillName), sm.SelectSingleNode ("skill").InnerText);
        int tv = System.Convert.ToInt32(sm.SelectSingleNode ("value").InnerText);
        tg.AddSkillModifier (ts, tv);
    }

    genders.Add (tg);
    length++;

    Debug.Log ("Increased length by 1, length is now " + length);
}
```

Commenting my inner for loop will give me a length of 3 so the part the code fails at is child nodes.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GenderManager.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Managers/GenderManager.cs:36)
```

Which is

```
int ta = (int)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(AttributeName), am.SelectSingleNode ("attribute").InnerText);
```

That line

I am going to assume that ChildNodes doesn't work the way I expect it to work.

The Gender Class (gender.cs)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Gender {

    private string _name;
    private string _desc;
    private List<GenderBonusAttribute> _attributeMods;
    private List<GenderBonusSkill> _skillMods;

    public Gender () {
        _name = string.Empty;
        _attributeMods = new List<GenderBonusAttribute> ();
        _skillMods = new List<GenderBonusSkill> ();
    }

    public string Name {
        get {return _name;}
        set {_name = value;}
    }

    public string Desc {
        get {return _desc;}
        set {_desc = value;}
    }

    public void AddAttributeModifier (int a, int v) {
        _attributeMods.Add (new GenderBonusAttribute (a, v));
    }

    public void AddSkillModifier (int s, int v) {
        _skillMods.Add (new GenderBonusSkill (s, v));
    }

    public List<GenderBonusAttribute> AttributeMods {
        get {return _attributeMods;}
    }

    public List<GenderBonusSkill> SkillMods {
        get {return _skillMods;}
    }
}

public class GenderBonusAttribute {
    public int attribute;
    public int value;

    public GenderBonusAttribute (int a, int v) {
        attribute = a;
        value = v;
    }
}

public class GenderBonusSkill {
    public int skill;
    public int value;

    public GenderBonusSkill (int s, int v) {
        skill = s;
        value = v;
    }
}
```

Edit: Added AttributeName and SkillName

```
public enum AttributeName {
    Strength,
    Agility,
    Quickness,
    Endurance,
    Attunement,
    Focus
};

public enum SkillName {
    Weight_Capacity,
    Attack_Power,
    Intimidation,
    Coercion,
    Charm
}
```

Edit #2: If I manually add the genders with their values it work, so I am 99.8% sure that it is the foreach loops not working, which puts me pretty sure at the doc.Childnodes not working they way I expect them to work.

Comment: How `SkillName` and `AttributeName` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `doc.ChildNodes` within the loop, and not use current `gender` element?

Change both `ams` and `sms` declarations to:

```
XmlNodeList ams = g.SelectNodes("attributemodifiers/attributemodifier");
```

```
XmlNodeList sms = g.SelectNodes("skillmodifiers/skillmodifier");
```

*PS. Any particular reason why you don't use LINQ to XML? It would be much easier with LINQ.*

Comment: I tried those first. Wierd, I guess I used them wrong or misspelled something. Thank you, it now works (except I had some lousy errors in my xml file I found out, thankfully the debug handled that for me) No there is no particular reason for not using it. Is it recommended?

Comment: It's newer, more dev-friendly way of dealing with XML in .NET. I don't advice you to switch now, when you have working solution using `XmlDocument`, but for new code you should consider trying LINQ to XML.

Comment: Is it faster, more secure? Does it have better exception handling?

Comment: There is almost no difference between them, but LINQ to XML exposes much batter API, which allows you to express queries more natural and write your code faster. Exception handling is as good as you write it, but when used properly you don't need any at all.